# Override element.style in Wordpress (CSS)

Tags: css, wordpress

I try to edit the height of a logo in mobile version of the site. 
What I figured out is that I need mobile height to be 50% and when I inspect it it shows 100%

```css
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px)
    header.centered_logo .q_logo {
    height: 50% !important;


    .q_logo {
    height: 50% !important;
```

```html
    <div class="q_logo"><a href="https://rzeczownik.com/" style="height: 60px; visibility: visible;"><img class="normal" src="https://rzeczownik.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/rzeczownik_logo.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 100%;"><img class="light" src="https://rzeczownik.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/rzeczownik_logo.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 100%;"><img class="dark" src="https://rzeczownik.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/rzeczownik_logo.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 100%;"><img class="sticky" src="https://rzeczownik.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/rzeczownik_logo.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 100%;"></a></div>
```

[image: printscreen of the site / click]

I have tried to edit css but without any success.

Comment: The CSS is not valid, you're missing the closing braces

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows a media query with styles which will be applied when the minimum width is 1000px.

You should change it to "max-width". Also, the CSS seems to be missing some curly brakets.

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
   .q_logo a img {
       height: 50% !important;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Victor! I've added the code but unfortunately is not working :( [link|(http://pl.tinypic.com/r/1ina4h/9) [link](http://pl.tinypic.com/r/2i8jbsm/9)

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the caching or CSS bundler of your theme. I just checked the .css file which should contain the custom CSS but the changes you show in the screenshot are not present. Also, there is some CSS code with syntax errors: https://imgur.com/duApu08 

Maybe try flushing the cache or regenerating the CSS files to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

it is issue with your anchor tag, you won't be able to set the height of the image since the default display property of anchor tag is inline, you might need to change that to `display:inline-block;` for treating the image inside it like a block element.

Answer (score 0):

You've to remove the inline css from html "style="height: 100%;"" after thar follow the given css.[image: attach image]

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px)
header .q_logo img.normal {
    display: block!important;
    opacity: 1!important;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<img class="normal" src="https://rzeczownik.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/rzeczownik_logo.png" alt="Logo" scale="0" style="">
```